# How to use Proxy configurations in WebView (Android)?

Tags: android, webview, proxy

I've searched a lot in SOF and still haven't found a solution for my problem. 
I need to write the app  which is using proxy configuration (including login and password) and connecting to some blocked url. 
I use this:

```
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    WebView.enablePlatformNotifications();
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://m.facebook.com/"); 
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
         public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin,
                  GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {            
            callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
         }
        });
```

And this:

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT_INT);
    httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRouteParams.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
    httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
        new AuthScope(PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT_INT),
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials(USERNAME, PASSWORD));
```

I think I should connect these parts somehow. But I don't know how :(

Answer (score 0):

WebView takes care of HTTP request/response by itself. You are trying to use a new HTTP client to fetch the HTTP response. While there is a way to display the response from a DefaultHttpClient in a WebView (see this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3007978/255872), this is very cumbersome. Instead, you can directly set proxy on the WebView.

While there is no API to set proxy on a WebView, it is possible to do it using Reflection. Check this SO post - [WebView android proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488338/webview-android-proxy)